# Различные варианты загрузки веб страницы

Tags: jquery, javascript, html, css

Добрый день. 
У меня задание - расписать варианты загрузки веб страницы - в зависимости от обстоятельств: скрипт/ стиль подключен в начале/конце страницы, теги style, script внутри веб страницы , ресурсы и ещё какие-то ситуации. Вопрос - напишите все такие возможные ситуации. Например я не знаю какие ресурсы могу быть кроме картинок и можно ли их подключать внутри страницы.

Comment: @olegall, это тестовое задание к собеседованию? У других не знаю как, но у меня особая политика по таким случаям.

Comment: я не прошу написать ответ, просто описать ситуации. как/куда подключают скрипты/стили и в каких случаях. я прохожу обучение, это одно из заданий

Answer (score 3):

> в зависимости от обстоятельств: скрипт/ стиль подключен в начале/конце страницы, теги style, script внутри веб страницы

Пока реусрс не подгружен, он не будет влиять на отображение и работу страницы. Насколько понимаю, современные браузеры не начинают ничего отображать, пока не получат весь заданный в шапке css, если css идет посреди страницы, то, думаю, он не будет применен, пока не будет получен. Подключенный в head скрипт может не иметь (и скорее всего не будет иметь) доступ ни к какому dom-дереву в момент загрузки, потому что в момент парсинга head содержимого body еще не существует. Точно так же скрипт в середине странице "не увидит" все, что описывается после него. При использовании события window.onload, насколько понимаю, особой разницы не будет, скрипт сработает тогда, когда все дерево и все скрипты подгрузятся (здесь могу ошибаться).

Инлайн-описание (прямо в теле страницы, внутри `<style>` и `<script>`) стилей/js увеличивает время загрузки страницы, но уменьшает количество запросов и не требует ожидания загрузки этого css/js для его работы.

> Например я не знаю какие ресурсы могу быть кроме картинок и можно ли их подключать внутри страницы.

iframe, те же css/js